# why is EditText objet not getting the text

Tags: android

so I was testing and I came to accost a problem. the following is falling to retrieve the text

```
    public void SetName(){

    try{
        EditText editText = new EditText(MainActivity.getAppContext());
        editText = editText.findViewById(R.id.idExample);
        name =  editText.getText().toString();
    }catch (Exception e){Toast.makeText( MainActivity.getAppContext() , "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

when I tested to see why I got the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

I think it has to do with how I call the context
on

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          MainActivity.appContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

public static Context getAppContext() {
    return appContext;
}
```

but if it is the problem I don't know how to fix it

Edit text object

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/idExample"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="Name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="@string/string" />
```

Comment: can you show your xml file which has the edittext !

Comment: the hole file or just like what I put up.

Comment: Have you got the solution yet?

Comment: I'm still tying some things but not yet

Comment: Why are you making an object of edittext? You can just pass the value of edittext from mainActivity!

Comment: Please add the whole mainActivity.java and the model class which has setName() method

Comment: that is what got me the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your EditText is there in activity , you should write this code

```
  public void SetName(){

    try{
        EditText editText =findViewById(R.id.idExample);
        name =  editText.getText().toString();
    }catch (Exception e){Toast.makeText( MainActivity.getAppContext() , "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

if EditText is these in fragment or layout be included

get View from fragment on method onCreateView and return this view

```
View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout , parent , false)
```

```
  public void SetName(){
    try{

        editText = view.findViewById(R.id.idExample);
        name =  editText.getText().toString();
    }catch (Exception e){Toast.makeText( MainActivity.getAppContext() , "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the issue is here , the first edittext is being executed instead of the second so make sure you delete this line of code

`EditText editText = new EditText(MainActivity.getAppContext());`

- Your code should be like this now

```
  try{
       
        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.idExample); 
        name =  editText.getText().toString();
    }catch (Exception e){Toast.makeText( MainActivity.getAppContext() , "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Comment: when I deleted it, it made an the error occur. I know because it now triggering the catch statement.

Comment: why are you using the try and catch here ?

Comment: testing purposes, it will be removed when I get it working

Comment: so what is your issue now ?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: oh i found the issue check my code again i ll make an edit for you

Answer (score 1):

The Id defined in XML for `Edittext` is `idExample`
but you are using id as `IDExamble`
Change `R.id.IDExamble` to `R.id.idExample`

Answer (score 1):

thats probably because your editText object is empty for some reason , try declaring `EditText editText` on top of your mainactivity class and then use  `editText = editText.findViewById(R.id.IDExamble);` inside onCreate method 
 then call use `editText` wherever you like